# Google Analytics real time not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-analytics

I am using this code for using `Google Analytics` for getting real time info and App Review, the code is in the AppDelegate:

```
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
[[GAI sharedInstance].logger setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = kGANDispatchPeriodSec;
self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithName:@"APP_NAME" trackingId:kGoogleAnalyticsCode];
self.tracker.allowIDFACollection = NO;
[self.tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"APP_NAME"];
[self.tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
```

And i get this Log in the console:

```
VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.13 +[GAITrackerModel initialize] (GAITrackerModel.m:88): idfa class missing, won't collect idfa
VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.13 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:517): Saved hit: {
    parameters =     {
        "&_crc" = 0;
        "&_s" = 10;
        "&_u" = ".etnK9L";
        "&_v" = "mi3.1.3";
        "&av" = "1.0";
        "&dm" = "iPhone7,2";
        "&ds" = app;
        "&sr" = 750x1334;
        "&t" = screenview;
        "&ul" = "en-il";
        "&v" = 1;
        gaiVersion = "3.13";
    };
    timestamp = "2015-10-08 13:36:40 +0000";
}
VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.13 __70-[GAIBatchingDispatcher checkIAdCampaignAttributionWithHitParameters:]_block_invoke (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:749): iAd campaign tracking disabled because the iAd framework is not linked. See http://goo.gl/426NGa for instructions.
INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.13 -[GAIReachabilityChecker reachabilityFlagsChanged:] (GAIReachabilityChecker.m:159): Reachability flags update: 0X000002
```

Any idea what can be the issue that i don't see nothing in the real-time console of `Google Analytics`??

Comment: when you integrated GA in your app

Comment: Try sending **screen name** inside a ViewController's ViewDidLoad method, on in AppDelegate send an event to see if it's working. Also if you've just created, your analytics application you should wait a few time until it will show you datas

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik in the `AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: Hi @MTA , did you get solution for this ?

Comment: Hi @RohitWankhede , I didn't found any solution, instead i start to use Flurry analytics

Comment: add  tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES; Worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should add iAd.framework in **TARGETS** -> **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** -> **+** -> **iAd.framework**

Self explanatory screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Please Explain Properly

Comment: @AbdulRauf I fixed this issue for my app but I forgot what i did i ill check and update you.