# iOS - In Real-Time : "active user on app" always show "0" In Google Analytics

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, event-tracking

I have done the following code in my app.

```
            id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"My Track Id"];
            [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"Show User"
                                                                  action:@"Show user Clicked"
                                                                   label:nil
                                                                   value:nil] build]];
```

I have installed my app in 3 or more devices, But i can not see the right now active user. It show me 0 always. How can i solve the problem.

Comment: when you integrated the analytics in your app

Comment: I integrate the analytics yesterday in my app. I also see the Total Event and Screens but the active user on app is not shown

Comment: see this link may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017566/google-analytics-real-time-not-working/33021538#33021538

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - Thanks for give me reference link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve the issue. I have just add the following code in `AppDelegate.m` file in my app.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
   [[GAI sharedInstance].logger setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
   [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
   [[GAI sharedInstance]dispatch];

   return YES;
}
```

Comment: you do not need to call * dispatch * it will be automaticly sent.

 If this value is positive, tracking information will be automatically
 dispatched every dispatchInterval seconds. Otherwise, tracking information must be sent manually by calling dispatch.